# Laravel 4 home redirecting to www.ipaddress and failing

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel-4

My current .htaccess file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have laravel 4 installed on an ubuntu 14.04 distribution.
My apache.config file looks like this:

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And my 000-default.config is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 DocumentRoot /var/www/public
<Directory /var/www/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Laravel's installed in /var/www
What I experience however is that when I try to navigate to the IP of the site (no domain attached). I get redirected to www.ip_address
for example 178.1.2.3 would have me redirect to www.178.1.2.3.

Mod_rewrite is enabled. So I have no idea why this is happening.

Could anybody help?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like a primitive rewrite logic. But since web sites usually are _not_ accessed by an IP address, actually typically _cannot_ be addressed like that, I would not consider that an issue.

Comment: if it's redirecting, so it's not rewrite problem, the problem with redirecting. if You navigate to: http://178.1.1.1 and as result You're in www.178.1.1.1 so it means in Your code somewhere it's redirection happens. it's not apache issue, it's in laravel app code. You've to find such code where it redirects and comment it. Normal app must not redirect to www.HOSTNAME, redirection must be in web server level, not in app level.

Comment: Sorry clarified it wasn't an issue with the ip address.
The site was happily working via IP prior to AllowOverride All hence my confusion

Comment: @DavidG, I'm moving my comment to answer, so Your problem is not with apache configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's redirecting, so it's not rewrite problem, the problem with redirecting.

If You navigate to: http://178.1.1.1 and as result You're in http://www.178.1.1.1 so it means in Your code somewhere redirection happens.

it's not apache issue, it's in laravel app code.

To prove it You can put in `/var/www/public/index.php` after `<?php`:

```
die($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

it will show You that web server rewrites properly.

You've to find such code where it redirects and comment it.

Normal app must not redirect to www.HOSTNAME, redirection must be in web server level, not in app level.

Comment: You are right, I am silly to not have realised. When I pointed a domain at it temporarily all worked fine. Sorry for the crap question stack, but thank you num8er for pointing me to the solution

Comment: actually it's normal to have solution for quick issues. my answer useful not only for You and also anyone who can lost in searching solution for such situations. happy that I was helpful. (: